# Replace characters with particular format with a variable value in python

Tags: python, string, replace

I have filenames with the particular format as given

```
II.NIL.10.BHZ.M.2058.190.160877
II.NIL.10.BHA.M.2008.190.168857   
II.NIL.10.BHB.M.2078.198.160857
.
.
.
```

I want to remove the `BH?.M` part with the value in a string variable in `name`.

`name=['T','D','FG'.....]`

expected output

```
II.NIL.10.BHT.2058.190.160877
II.NIL.10.BHD.2008.190.168857   
II.NIL.10.BHFG.2078.198.160857
.
.
.
```

Is it possible with `str.replace()`?

Comment: `str.replace()` doesn't work with wildcards. You could use [re.sub()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.sub) instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the built-in regex module (`re`) alongside the following pattern to effectively replace the content in your strings.

**Pattern**

```
'(?<=BH)[A-Z]+\.M'
```

This pattern looks behind (non-matching) to ensure to check for the substring `'BH'`, then matches on any uppercase character `[A-Z]` one or more times `+` followed by the substring `'.M'`.

**Solution**

The below solution uses `re.sub()` alongside the pattern outlined above to return a string with the substring matched by the pattern replaced with that defined here as `replacement`.

```py
import re

original = 'II.NIL.10.BHB.M.2078.198.160857'
replacement = 'FG'
output = re.sub(r'(?<=BH)[A-Z]+\.M', replacement, original)

print(output)
```

**Output**

```
II.NIL.10.BHFG.2078.198.160857
```

**Processing multiple files**

To repeat this process for multiple files you could apply the above logic within a loop/comprehension, running the `re.sub()` function on each `original`/`replacement` pairing and storing/processing appropriately.

The below example uses the data from your original question alongside the above logic to create a list containing the results of each `re.sub()` operation by way of a dictionary mapping between the original filenames and substrings to be inserted using `re.sub()`.

```py
import re

originals = [
    'II.NIL.10.BHZ.M.2058.190.160877',
    'II.NIL.10.BHA.M.2008.190.168857',   
    'II.NIL.10.BHB.M.2078.198.160857'
]

replacements = ['T','D','FG']

mapping = {originals[i]: replacements[i] for i, _ in enumerate(originals)}

results = [re.sub(r'(?<=BH)[A-Z]+\.M', v, k) for k,v in mapping.items()]

for r in results:
    print(r)
```

**Output**

```
II.NIL.10.BHT.2058.190.160877
II.NIL.10.BHD.2008.190.168857
II.NIL.10.BHFG.2078.198.160857
```

Answer (score 1):

Nope, you cannot use `str.replace` with a wildcard. You will have to use regex with something such as the following

```py
import re

filenames = ['II.NIL.10.BHA.M.2008.190.168857 ', 'II.NIL.10.BHB.M.2078.198.160857', 
'II.NIL.10.BHC.M.2078.198.160857']
name = ['T','D','FG']

newfilenames = []

for i in range(len(filenames)):
    newfilenames.append(re.sub(r'BH.?\.M', 'BH'+name[i], filenames[i]))

print(' '.join(newfilenames)) # outputs II.NIL.10.BHT.2008.190.168857  II.NIL.10.BHD.2078.198.160857 II.NIL.10.BHFG.2078.198.160857
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `iter` with `next` in the replacement `lambda` of `re.sub`:

```
import re
name = iter(['T','D','FG'])
s = """
  II.NIL.10.BHZ.M.2058.190.160877
  II.NIL.10.BHA.M.2008.190.168857   
  II.NIL.10.BHB.M.2078.198.160857
  """
result = re.sub('(?<=BH)\w\.\w', lambda x:f'{next(name)}', s)
```

Output:

```
II.NIL.10.BHT.2058.190.160877
II.NIL.10.BHD.2008.190.168857   
II.NIL.10.BHFG.2078.198.160857
```